# Where can I see Firebase Crash Reporting for existing App

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, firebase-crash-reporting

As firebase started supporting Crashlytics the Firebase crash reporting option is no longer available. Is there any way to see the **Firebase crash reporting** for the existing app which already using **Firebase crash reporting**

Answer (score 3):

Mike from Firebase here. If you don't see the screen that Yogesh mentioned, from the Crashlytics dashboard, click on your app under Crashlytics and you should see both Crashlytics and Crash Reporting mentioned in order to switch between the dashboards.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image: firebase]

If your project using crash reporting, then it is showing like this.

[image: firebase]

or like this

Comment: when did you add crash reporting to your app

Comment: 2-3 weeks back.

Comment: can you provide me the url of crashlytics page

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: open crashlytics of your app in firebase and copy the url from the bar.

Comment: How can u access that u it's with my acoount

Comment: i can't access, but i will make a url that will directly take to your cras reporting

Comment: @YogeshPaliyal I've been struggling to figure out the URL pattern for Crash Reporting. But if you know the basic URL, you don't need Anirban's URL to help. Take a URL from your project, and replace the project ID with an `_`. The resulting URL takes you to the project selection page, and then immediately to the feature page for that project. Give it a try and let me know.

Comment: here is for my project
https://console.firebase.google.com/u/2/project/MYPROJECTNAME/monitoring/app/android:APP_PACKAGE_NAME/crash

Comment: How u will make